# matlab plot different colors

Tags: matlab, colors, plot, points, scatter

I have set of **points** *(matrix Nx1)* and **groups** for this points *(matrix Nx1)*. I want to plot this points (there is no problem, I do this like this: `plot(points, groups, 'o');`), but I'd like to set unique color for each group. How can I do this? Now I have only two groups (1,2).

Comment: what do you mean by "groups"?

Comment: i mean that i have for example 100 point's [0..10], and if point <= 5 it's group is one, else two. Group - it's ordinate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use logical indexing to select the points you want

```
figure;
hold all; % keep old plots and cycle through colors

ind = (groups == 1); % select all points where groups is 1

% you can do all kind of logical selections here:
% ind = (groups < 5)

plot(points(ind), groups(ind), 'o');
```

Comment: ok, and what should I do if dimension of points and groups is two? how can I use only first col to draw a plot(points(ind), groups(ind), 'o');

Comment: @Yekver: I'm not sure if I understand what you want. You can index all rows of the first column by `points(ind, 1)`. If you want to create an index vector from the first column of a matrix, you can use `ind = (groups(:,1) == 1);`

Answer (score 2):

Given some random data:

```
points = randn(100,1);
groups = randi([1 2],[100 1]);
```

Here are a few more general suggestions:

```
g = unique(groups);           %# unique group values 
clr = hsv(numel(g));          %# distinct colors from HSV colormap
h = zeros(numel(g),1);        %# store handles to lines
for i=1:numel(g)
    ind = (groups == g(i));   %# indices where group==k
    h(i,:) = line(points(ind), groups(ind), 'LineStyle','none', ...
        'Marker','.', 'MarkerSize',15, 'Color',clr(i,:));
end
legend(h, num2str(g,'%d'))
set(gca, 'YTick',g, 'YLim',[min(g)-0.5 max(g)+0.5], 'Box','on')
xlabel('Points') ylabel('Groups')
```

[image: scatter_lines]

If you have access to the Statistics Toolbox, there is a function that simplifies all of the above in one call:

```
gscatter(points, groups, groups)
```

Finally, in this case, it would be more suitable to display the [Box plot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_plot):

```
labels = num2str(unique(groups),'Group %d');
boxplot(points,groups, 'Labels',labels)
ylabel('Points'), title('Distribution of points across groups')
```

[image: boxplot]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the number of groups is known a-priori:

```
plot(points(find(groups == 1)), groups(find(groups == 1)), points(find(groups == 2)), groups(find(groups == 2)));
```

`find` will give you all the indices of `groups` for which the condition holds.  You use the output of `find` as a subvector of both `points` and `groups` for each possible value of `groups`.

When you use `plot` to plot more than one x-y combination, it uses a different color for each.

Alternatively, you could just choose each color explicitly:

```
hold on
plot(points(find(groups == 1)), groups(find(groups == 1)), 'r')
plot(points(find(groups == 2)), groups(find(groups == 2)), 'y')
```

Finally, there's a way to tell plot to cycle through the colors automatically, so that you can call `plot` without specifying a color, but the method eludes me.

Comment: If you set 'hold all', each time you call plot it will add to the same figure but will cycle through the default colormap and line style.